# is excel in ready mode when msgbox displays?

Tags: excel, msgbox, vba

Just curious.

This is a more theoretical (related to Excel VBA) question. Rather than a trying to solve a particular problem. I have learnt that Excel has ready, cut, copy and other modes. I am just wondering what mode it is when a msgbox is displayed.

If it is not in ready mode, what mode is it in?
(Could it be cut, copy mode or something else?)

Answer (score 1):

> I am just wondering what mode it is when a msgbox is displayed.

The mode is called "**Click the Damn Button**" Mode!!! :D

Jokes apart, it is the `Ready Mode`. The best way to test it is to launch a `Msgbox` and then check the status bar.

`Ready` mode indicates a general state.

[image]

**EDIT**: One thing I would like to mention. If you `Copy` a cell say using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and then immediately show a `Msgbox` then the mode changes to `xlCopy`. Similarly if you `Cut` a cell using say <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and then immediately show a `Msgbox` then the mode changes to `xlCut`. See this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Select Case Application.CutCopyMode
        Case Is = False: MsgBox "Not in Cut or Copy mode"
        Case Is = xlCopy: MsgBox "In Copy mode"
        Case Is = xlCut: MsgBox "In Cut mode"
    End Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: and I am very sad to realize that the macro would stop running when the msgbox pop up.